# How can we use K means algorithm for clustering using Gower's method

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

How can we use gower's method for clustering using kmeans algorithm?

Comment: k-means by definition uses the sum of squares as loss function. If you use "Gower's method" (by which I assume you mean Gower's dissimilarity coefficient?) it's no longer k-means.

Comment: PS: Some people use the term k-means with general dissimilarity functions potentially including Gower's method, but this is misleading, (a) because in that case the optimal centroids are no longer means, and (b) because there is more than one way to generalise k-means in this way and the people who use the term like this usually don't know that.

Comment: What is Gower method?